# Undefined function or method 'int' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, int

I have written a code to evaluate the critical values of flow rate in peristaltic pumping

```
dp = -(((theta - 1)+(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x))).*M.^3.*(cosh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)+ M.*beta.*sinh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)))./((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.*cosh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)+(-1 +(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.^2.*beta).*sinh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M))-(alpha.*(M.^2.*((theta - 1)+(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x))).*(-1+2.*(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).^2.*M.^2+ cosh(2.*(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)-2.*(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.*sinh(2.*(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)))./(8.*((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.*cosh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)+(-1+(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.^2.*beta).*sinh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)).^2));
```

and `p = int(y,x,0,1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x));`

what is critical value of theta if at critical value of theta p = 0;
I wrote the code:

```
M = 2;
alpha = 0.2;
beta = 0.03;
phi = 0.6;
theta = 0;
x = 0.5;
y = -(((theta - 1)+(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x))).*M.^3.*(cosh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)+ M.*beta.*sinh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)))./((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.*cosh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)+(-1 +(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.^2.*beta).*sinh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M))-(alpha.*(M.^2.*((theta - 1)+(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x))).*(-1+2.*(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).^2.*M.^2+ cosh(2.*(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)-2.*(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.*sinh(2.*(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)))./(8.*((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.*cosh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)+(-1+(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.^2.*beta).*sinh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)).^2));
p = int(y,x,0,1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x));
sym theta
solve( 'p','theta' );
```

to check for one point, but i am getting

```
Undefined function or method 'int' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Can you help? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is Symbolic Integration, you need **Symbolic Toolbox** that [INT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/int.html) function belong to. The variables should be symbolic (defined with `sym` or `syms`). Check the function syntax with examples in the documentation.